# Google Custom Search with custom search box?

Tags: javascript, css, search-engine, google-custom-search

I am looking to add a Google Custom Search to my site but I have already styled the search box placeholder and I was hoping to have my search box look that way.

After some searching, it seems all the previous questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174187/google-custom-search-with-custom-search-box-and-button) are outdated.

The only thing I have found with regards to styling is this:

```
<script>
    (function() {
    var cx = 'XXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYY';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>
<div style="width:0px;overflow:hidden;height:0px;"> <!-- if you use display:nonw here it doesn't work-->
    <gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
<form id="searchbox_XXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYY" action="">
    <input value="XXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYY" name="cx" type="hidden"/>
    <input value="FORID:11" name="cof" type="hidden"/>
    <input id="q" style="" name="q" size="75" type="text"/>
    <button class="btn">Search</button>
</form>
```

However, when you submit the form, nothing happens.

I noticed the action="" was left blank, and when I inputted my site "www.kokorugs.com/" it did not work either.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I found was to use JQuery to create hooks into the rendered Google elements. Since you want to hook your custom search box into the elements, you should render **gsce:results-only** instead of **gsce:search** and follow the implementation of one of my previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35754330/4830578).